# problems with NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am sorry of the question, but i have searched but i have not found the solution.
I have a textField, and i would like to add a caractère to the text of my textField. how to do this, please ?

```
if ( myConddition) {

otherTextField.text = myTextField.text ( a would like to add a caractér("1") to the first position ).
```

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
otherTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1%@", myTextField.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
NSMutableString* myString = [NSMutableString alloc] appendFormat:@"%@%@",@"1", myTextField.text]];
myTextField.text = myString;
[myString release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
otherTextField.text = [@"1" stringByAppendingString:myTextField.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've created @property declarations...

```
[[self otherTextField] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1%@", [[self myTextField] text]]];
```

P.S.  Eww at the use of [dot notation](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=83) by you boys and girls.